# data annotation is not working when button type is "button" instead of submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a mvc application.I have used data annotations for validation.
My class is

```
 public class AdviceCreateVM
      {       
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required")]
            public int CompanyId { get; set; }
     }
```

my view is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdviceCreate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmCreate"}))

{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9 roundedDiv" style="margin-left: 10px;">

            <div class=" row-fluid Span12" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <label>Company</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, Model.Companies.Select(company => new SelectListItem { Value = company.Id.ToString(), Text = company.Name }), "--Select Company--")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId)
                    </div>
                </div>
         <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Create" id="create" />
}
```

I used button without submit action and post data from view to controller using ajax.
jquery code is,

```
 var obj =$("#frmCreate").serializeArray(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "AdviceCreate")',
              type: 'POST',                 
              data:obj,                 
              success: function (data) {             
                  window.location.href='@Url.Action("index")';              
                }
          });
```

My question is that,when "companyId" is null and if i click on create button it should display message from data annotation .but message dose not displays.
any solution?

Comment: You need to wire jquery/javascript event to the button click and call validate() method on the form.

Comment: @Dhanashri Kadam 'data annotation' will work on HttpPost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks familiar. As you are manually submitting the form, call the

```
$("#frmCreate").validate();
if($("#frmCreate").valid())
{

var obj =$("#frmCreate").serializeArray(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "AdviceCreate")',
              type: 'POST',                 
              data:obj,                 
              success: function (data) {             
                  window.location.href='@Url.Action("index")';              
                }
          });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire jquery/javascript event to the button click and call validate() method on the form.

```
$("#buttonSubmit").click(function(){
     if($("form").validate())
     {
           //Post to server or other stuff, if the validation successful
     }
});
```

This is a pseudo code like, to provide an idea.